# Is cloneNode(true) an option here?

Tags: javascript, dom

I *think* the answer here is "no," but I wanted to double-check....

I've got    article which looks basically like this....

```
<article id="thisArticle">
  <h1 id="thisHeader"></h1>
  <ul class="thisList">
    <li class-"listItem">some content</li>
    <li class-"listItem">some content</li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

....and I want to copy it off-DOM using     cloneNode and change its content, but obviously need to change the the ids on both the     article and the     h1 tags.  Doing it on the article is easy: either use JavaScript    setAtrribute or jQuery    .attr() (the latter's probably better). But I'm not sure how to target the     h1 so I can change its id.

I'm assuming that I can't use    cloneNode(true) and copy both the parent and its children.  Instead, I'll have to use    cloneNode(false) and just copy the parent, then add the children manually with    createElement and    appendChild.  Which is fine, but I'm not 100% sure. As an FYI, I'm not copying over any data and/or events.

Thanx in advance for the assistance.

Comment: You can easily copy the node with descendantes and then iterate through the descendants and make the necessary changes. It's still DOM, so you can use any DOM traversal methods or jQuery methods/selectors to get the elements you want.

Comment: Hi Felix...thanks for answering.  I tried that and every time I used a DOM traversal method to target the header (such as $('#header') for example), it targeted the header on the page instead of the header located in the article I cloned off-DOM. Not sure what I'm missing/misunderstanding here.

Comment: You have to search *relative* to the cloned node. For example: `$(clonedNode).find('#header')` or even `$(clonedNode).children().first()`. Read through the traversal methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: Ahh...a relative search makes sense.  Thanx!